Use websocket 'accountSubscribe' to get SWAP token address
hello i'm trying to  use websocket's  'accountSubscribe' to get SWAP token address.
I establish ws connection, use  use 'accountSubscribe' and as there is a signal i use another api to check what swap happened and what coin was bought or sold.
I know for sure there is a way to get that swap token address directly from ws signal and skip another api request. This can be sone using accountSubscribe or programSubscribe but i cant figure out how.
please help if you know thanks

upd: i noticed some of the wallets that i track dont have data i nwebsocket signal and some wallets have - why is that?

{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'accountNotification', 'params': {'result': {'context': {'slot': 266171393}, 'value': {'lamports': 8836715, 'data': ['P5XRDOGAYwkT5EH4ORPKaLBjT7Al/eqohzfoQRDRJV41ezN33e4czf4IAAgA9AEBAMSMvNbPZAAAAAAAAAAAAACZ3uXHsNDRqgIAAAAAAAAApkwAAFfXC', 'base64'], 'owner': 'whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc', 'executable': False, 'rentEpoch': 18446744073709551615, 'space': 653}}, 'subscription': 848198}}     - some wallets have data in base64 and some wallets dont have it. why?
